# How can i place zip files in a folder during installation of an msi?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

The solution exists out of a wpf project and a setup project. When the user will run the msi, I also want to place some zip files on the file system of the target machine. These zip files would be placed under an already existing path on the target machine (has to be checked for during installation).

Is there a way to implement this by copying the zip archives in the solution and adding file system entries (how?). Or should this be done with "custom action" on the setup project (again, how?).

Comment: Are you using WiX?

Comment: @SebastianL No, i'm working in Visual Studio 2015 Community, with the normal Setup Project from the "Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension.

Comment: then you need to include them into your solution, if you need more complex installation logic i would recommend WiX (http://wixtoolset.org/)

Comment: @SebastianL Include them in the setup-project, or in the wpf-project? And where would I set the instructions of what to do with the file?

Comment: You can just add the .zip files to your setup project in the folder you want. I suspect you're using "project output" as the input to your setup, but you can just add individual zip files (or any files at all for that matter).